# Cakephp 3 - Cache function throws PDOException

Tags: php, caching, pdo, cakephp-3.0

I'm wan't to build some caching inside my Cakephp 3 application. So i've added the Cache::remember() function to check for existing migrations like below.

The data will be cached but Iv'e some problems with the prefix. When I used a prefix like "migrations" it's working, but when I add some vars it will return a pdo exeption:

```
PDOException
You cannot serialize or unserialize PDO instances
```

Why I can't use `self::CACHE_KEY_PREFIX . "_" . $plugin . "_" . $file . "_" . $path` as cache key?

```
const CACHE_KEY_PREFIX = 'migrations';

public function isMigrated($plugin, $file, $path)
{

    $cacheResult = function () {
        return TableRegistry::get('Migrations');
    };

    // Get from cache or new 
    $MigrationsTable = Cache::remember(
        self::CACHE_KEY_PREFIX, // Only this prefix as key works fine 
        self::CACHE_KEY_PREFIX . "_" . $plugin . "_" . $file . "_" . $path, // But when I add some extra info to the prefix it doesn't works
        $cacheResult,
        'cache-1-week'
    );

    // Find migration
    $isExisting = $MigrationsTable->exists([
        'plugin'    => $plugin,
        'file'      => $file,
        'path'      => $path,
    ]);

    return $isExisting;
}
```

Comment: Any chance one of those variables is an object instead of a simple string? If that's truly the only change you're making, then the error must be in one of them.

Comment: Yes, it are only strings inside the key. The strange thing is that when I add a string like ‘. “test”’ so it’s not defined as variabele it is woking. Ive also this problem by other implementations.

Comment: It *really* sounds like one of those things isn't actually a string. Have you done `gettype` on each of the variables in there to be 100% sure?